# Consolidate .csv File to One Row per Unique Key (Example, Person) in Python

Tags: python, csv

### What I Have

I have a .csv file with a list of employee's and their shifts for a given day that looks like this:

```
Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd
BAB,Smith,Bob,10:00a,1:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,11:00a,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,1:00p,4:00p
BAB,Smith,Bob,1:00p,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,5:00p,9:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:00p,3:30p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:30p,5:00p
DJM,Martin,Dominique,8:00a,11:00a
```

Note how one person can have more than one shift, the start time for the next shift might or might not be the same as the end time for another shift, and each employee is identified by their initials as a unique identifier (suitable for use as a key.)

### What I Want

I want to consolidate this .csv file so that there is only one row per employee.  If that person has more than one shift then check to see if the end time for one shift is the same as the start time for another and combine those shifts but if not then add two new columns 2ndShiftStart and 2ndShiftEnd and put that data there.

The result should look like this:

```
Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd,2ndShiftStart,2ndShiftEnd
BAB,Smith,Bob,10:00a,3:00p,,
JCJ,Jones,Jill,11:00a,5:00p,,
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,1:00p,4:00p,5:00p,9:00p
DJM,Martin,Dominique,8:00a,11:00a,,
```

BAB, for example, works 10 am - 1 pm then 1 pm - 3 pm so the resulting .csv lists him as working 10am - 3 pm.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is for a real world application or an assignment, but if it's for a real world application I would caution against using initials as a unique identifier. You're likely to get conflicts in any decently sized organization.

Comment: This goal seems a bit misguided. It makes more sense to put these data into a database: a person table and a shift table.

Comment: This is a real world application for a small company where I work.  (On the few rare occasions we have run into problems where two people have the same initials we use a letter like Q or X as the middle initial of one of them.)  As for a database, yes, I thought about using sqlite3 as an option, but it seemed a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
##Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd
s='''BAB,Smith,Bob,10:00a,1:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,11:00a,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,1:00p,4:00p
BAB,Smith,Bob,1:00p,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,5:00p,9:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:00p,3:30p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:30p,5:00p
DJM,Martin,Dominique,8:00a,11:00a'''

db = {}
for line in s.split('\n'):
     Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd = line.split(',')
     if Initials in db:
         db[Initials][2].append((ShiftStart,ShiftEnd))
     else:
         db[Initials] = (Last,First,[(ShiftStart,ShiftEnd)])
for Initials,v in db.iteritems():
    Last,First,shifts = v
    sys.stdout.write(Initials + ',')
    sys.stdout.write(Last + ',' + First)
    for shift in shifts:
        ShiftStart,ShiftEnd = shift
        sys.stdout.write(',' + ShiftStart + ',' + ShiftEnd)
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

Alternatively, you could do a very object-oriented program:

```
import sys
##Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd
s='''BAB,Smith,Bob,10:00a,1:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,11:00a,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,1:00p,4:00p
BAB,Smith,Bob,1:00p,3:00p
JIH,Hernandez,Jose,5:00p,9:00p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:00p,3:30p
JCJ,Jones,Jill,3:30p,5:00p
DJM,Martin,Dominique,8:00a,11:00a'''

class Shift(object):
    def __init__(self,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd):
        self.ShiftStart,self.ShiftEnd = ShiftStart,ShiftEnd
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s,%s' % (ShiftStart,ShiftEnd)

class Person(object):
    def __eq__(self, p):
        if self.Initials != p.Initials:
            return False
        if p.Last is not None and self.Last != p.Last:
            return False
        if p.First is not None and self.First != p.First:
            return False
        return True
    def __init__(self,Initials,Last,First):
        self.Initials,self.Last,self.First = Initials,Last,First
        self.Shifts = []
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s,%s,%s' % (self.Initials,self.Last,self.First)

def AddShift(people, person, shift):
    try:
        person = people[people.index(person)]
    except ValueError:
        people.append(person)
    person.Shifts.append(shift)

people = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
     Initials,Last,First,ShiftStart,ShiftEnd = line.split(',')
     AddShift(people, Person(Initials,Last,First), Shift(ShiftStart,ShiftEnd))

for person in people:
    print '%s,%s' %(person, ','.join(map(str,person.Shifts)))
```